# Can I claim my bitcoin gold if I have used my bitcoins few days ago?

Tags: bitcoin-gold

I had my bitcoins on blockchain.info when the fork happened. A few days ago I sold my bitcoins. Now I am wondering if there is a way I can claim my bitcoin gold? Blockchain.info support has said I can export my private keys and get them but I have no idea on how to do it. Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to claim your Bitcoin Gold with your private key. The snapshot of ownership for Bitcoin Gold was taken on October 25th, if you had bitcoins at that time, you'll get Bitcoin Gold.

In order to redeem it, you'll need to import your seed/private key in a Bitcoin Gold wallet, but beware of fake wallets that just want to steal your coins.